# VBA excel copy price from one column to another but before that check with another column

Tags: excel

Hi I need help I crawled maybe the whole internet but I can't find the answer to it please advise.

I have an excel sheet which looks like the picture below and I need a VBA script that can take the price from D2 and copy it to F2 - it's obviously simple, but what I don't know is that before copying I need the price from D2 to be checked according to buy price in E2 and if the copied price from D2 will not be at least 10% higher than the price in E2, i need to increase it to be at least 10% higher than the buy price in E2, of course if the price in D2 will be higher by more than 10% than in E2, so there is no need to do anything and just copy the price from D2 to F2 (I would like to change the percentages).

Of course, repeat this process line by line until the end of sheet

Please help.

[my real example form excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YmXFF.png)

Comment: Please provide the code for what you have tried so far.
Here is a guide on how to ask a question here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub Prices()
    Dim percentage As Double
    percentage = 1.1
    
    Dim i As Long
    Dim lastrow As Long
    lastrow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 1 To lastrow
        If Range("D" & i) <= Range("E" & i) * percentage Then
            Range("F" & i) = Range("E" & i) * percentage
        Else
            Range("F" & i) = Range("D" & i)
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: For i = 2 To lastrow if you want to start in the second row

Comment: You are amazing this code work exactly how i want THANK YOU!